# how to delete subcategory and display success message

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to delete a sub category and display a message about the deletion upon success.
However, my query does not delete anything. How can I fix it?

**table structure:**

```
Software 
CategoryID=100, SubCategoryID=NULL (main category)
Asp.Net
CategoryID=100, SubCategoryID=100 (sub category)`
```

code

```
if (Process == "Delete")
{
    system.cmd("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID =" + CategoryID);
    DeleteMsg.Visible = true;
}
```

Delete Message

```
      <div class="alert alert-info"  id="DeleteMsg" runat="server"  visible="false">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your SQL query. You should write:

```
     system.cmd("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID = " + CategoryID);
```

In addition you should use parameters in your SQL queries. It's more efficient and prevent from SQL injection attacks ([Adding parameter to command](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the query directly in code; first check the queries in Sql server management studio, because your query is not correct, I believe you want to delete all the sub categories below a specific category, if that is the case then you will match the category column and that is it.

Hope this helps

Comment: can u share the query plz? i cant do that?